# asp.net mvc2 microsoftMvcJqueryValidation - Include my custom client-side function

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, client-side-validation

I'm using microsoftMvcJqueryValidation and I want to call my own client-side validation function for a particular field with the system so that it fires with the other auto generated client-side validation.

Is there a certain place I can call my function?

Thanks~!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly what you described, but below I create a new javascript function, attach it to jQuery validator, and tell it to run on inputs with the class "monthDay":

```
// add a validation method for isMonthDay...
$.validator.addMethod("isMonthDay", function (value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || !/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value + "/2000"));
}, "Date must be in the form Month/Day");
// ...and associate it with the "monthDay" css class
$.validator.addClassRules({
    monthDay: {
        isMonthDay: true
    }
});
```

You could do the same thing where you create a validation function and register it with $.validator.  Then it's just a matter of associating the validation function with whatever input types/classes you want.  $.validator's API offers various ways of doing this.

Additionally, this does work with the auto-wiring of validation using MicrosoftMvcJqueryValidation.  In fact, it doesn't make a difference if it is or not as you're simply augmenting jQuery's validator plugin, independent of how it's invoked.